# Dynamic IBInspectable enum in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, ibinspectable

I'm writing custom control with segments (like UISegmentControl)
I have to use `IBInspectable` params.

I have number of controls

```
@property IBInspectable int numberOfSegments;
```

And here how I draw this segments:

```
-(void) drawForAmountOfSegments {
    float segmentWidth = self.frame.size.width / numberOfSegments;
    float segmentHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++) {

       CGRect sgRect = CGRectMake(segmentWidth * i, 0, segmentWidth, segmentHeight);
       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [button addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(segmentSelected:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       button.tag = i;
       button.frame = sgRect;
       button.backgroundColor = custom;
       [self addSubview: button];
    }
}
```

Now I want to set titles for this buttons (segments) And I want to select editing control from IB, like in segmentControl.

[image]

As I understand, I need an array of all segments, and by selecting one of it to edit its title.
But I can't to set `NSArray` as `IBInspectable`
Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

*** Edit ***

For example, I need to select from enum of segments single segment, and set its params.
Select first segment -> set its title (I can't understand how to realize it with IBInspectable)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `User Defined Runtime Attributes` from `Identity Inspector`.
All inspectable attributes actually add values there.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how can I select single segment?

Comment: @Arthur you can add special string property that generates titles. You can use there separated by `,` string or other input format, json for example.

Comment: @Arthur it's impossible. At least for now.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Thank you!